# wso2 BPEL message-variable becomes un-expandable after some time

Tags: eclipse, wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

I am using Developer Studio 3.8.0 on top of Eclipse Lunar to develop an BPEL project...

I have able to create a partner link, assign the input message variable, and invoke the partner link.

however, I found out that after sometime, the message variable (the input/output variable used when calling a partner link)   become un-expandable.

see the snapshot below

[image]

I tried to create a new message variable with the same partner link ( of different operation), and the message variable is expandable. (see shap shot below)

[image]

this is very annoying, because I am totally depending on the graphic designing iterface; and it become almost impossible to any job when complex composite variables become un-expandable in the GUI

anyone has any idea? or any suggestion?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Developer studio is using the JDT UI elements in Eclipse platform[1]. However in some cases, JDT UIs are not working properly with lower window resolutions. In your attached screenshots, we can see that it has very low resolution.

So please try to increase the resolution first. If it is not working, edit your bpel with the source view. You can switch to the source view by clicking on the source view tab in bottom of your Gups.bpel window.

[1] https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/

Comment: ok, i am somewhat relaxed to know that it was a software problems